# How to use react-router and have different types of animations (or none) with react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I've used React Router's own animation example as a starting point and gotten a simple always-fade-in animation working.

Problem is, that setup is way too simplistic, and I require anything from no transition at all to an arbitrary amount of transitions (say,  leftward and rightward directed motion, replicating IOS app transitions).

As soon as I start to tweak the `exit` and `enter` props of `TransitionGroup`, and change `classNames` of the `CSSTransition` things break down, and nothing works as if messing with already existing elements and creating a mangle of configs (I've tried moving the `exit` and `enter` props to `CSSTransition` to no avail):

```
<Route render={({ location }) => {
    let direction = location.state ? location.state.direction : null
    let doAnimation = !!direction 

    // direction = the type of animation to use, if null = no animation

    return (
        <TransitionGroup enter={doAnimation} exit={doAnimation} >
            <CSSTransition 
                key={location.key} 
                classNames={direction || "none"} 
                timeout={500}> 
                <Switch  
                    location={location}>
                    {routes}
                </Switch> 
            </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup> 
    )
}} />
```

Is there anyway of controlling animations like this, possibly disable them all together? If no, is there an animation/library providing native app like navigation and transitions for a browser app?